# "jt" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I tried changing the themes in jupyter notebook. Ran `pip install jupyterthemes` and installed it but when I enter `jt -l` it says:

```
jt is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

[image]